# Enterprise architect package checkout error

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

So i set up my EA project and downloaded several packages from our svn. And i really don't what I am doing wrong.

Some of the packages work correctly. I can check them out and in just fine. But somehow two of them when I try to check out them EA tells me that they are not version controlled.

To be more specific:

> The selected package cannot be checked-out at this time. The
>   configuration 'myconfigname', reports the file 'packagename.xml' as
>   'Not Controlled'.

The weirdest part: My team mates can access and checkout those packages just fine. And by what I asked them they didnt do anything differently.

Answer (score 2):

Try also `Project/Version Control/Re-synch...`

EA get's hick-ups at various places and this is one way to fix it again.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem today:

Right click on a pakcage | package control | Get all Latest.
When this is done try to checkout the problematic package again.

Comment: @Anderiel, Well, go to the SVN working copy. Is it up-to-date? Try to update it and then to get latest. Please let me know what happens.